# Unable to read file in python in w+ mode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, and I am currently learning file operations. I am unable to read from a file, that I just wrote into. I'm using w+ mode.

Also please tell me, what I'm doing wrong in the

textbuffer = str("%r\n %r\n %r\n" % input(), input(), input())
which is commented.

Below is the code snippet:

```
filename = '/home/ranadeep/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/ex15_sample.txt'
target = open(filename,'w+')
target.truncate()

print("Input the 3 lines: ")
textbuffer = "Just a demo text input"
#textbuffer = str("%r\n %r\n %r\n" % input(), input(), input())
target.write(textbuffer)
# read not working in w+ mode
print(target.read())
target.close()

# read only mode
updated_target = open(filename,'r')
print(updated_target.read())
```

Comment: After you have written to the file, the file object `target` is "at the end of the file". You have to go back a bit before you can read anything. You can use the `.tell` and `.seek` methods to see and change the position within the file. See the docs for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thanks. Got it. @jmd_dk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write to the file, the line you begin reading from only occurs after the line you wrote to. For this to work, you need to reset the "head" back to the beginning of the file.

```
target.write("blah")

# This is new
target.seek(0)

print target.read() 
target.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(file_name,"w+") as f:
    f.write("I love programming and i love python ")
    f.seek(0) #move cursor to the start of the file
    data=f.read()
    print(data)
```